# Where was Moses standing when he spoke the Shema?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, shema, vaeschanan, deuteronomy

Having a visual sometimes helps.

When reading scripture I like to visualize it.

I would like to be as accurate as possible.

If we went back in time to the moment Moses said "Hear O Israel", and were present there, what would it have been like?

Not just where he was standing, but what was around him? A camp fire?  Was it near a mountain?  Could they hear running water if a river was nearby?

So that I can memorize is my purpose, write it on my heart if you will.

(The stated goal of the question is to aid in remembering Torah.  But perhaps visualizing Torah is an incorrect way of going about this; could singing the Torah be a better solution?)

Visualizing it as I was actually there is the goal.

Not visualize it being written down, but visualize what's being wrote down.

Comment: OB7DEV, [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for this fascinating question! As Shema is reported in the Torah as part of Moses' final speeches that comprise the Book of [Deuteronomy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Deuteronomy), any clues about the environment during these speeches in general may be helpful. I'm adding a couple of tags accordingly.

Comment: I think that the answer to this question fits in with a far more generalized question - what was happening when Moses delivered any of the laws? Well, perhaps, the Shema is not exactly a law, and is a general part of his Deuterenomic speech, which may have had different circumstances than the other laws. Though, I doubt this is much different than the rest.

Comment: I'm uncertain of the reason for the "off topic" vote.

Comment: This sounds more like an exercise in creative writing than anything that could possibly be verified from sources.

Comment: questions reason is in the question; the exercise is to memorize the Torah not creative writing.